# Create a group of button that contain image in it

Tags: java

How can i create a group of button like the group in this picture ? [image of the group button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTwqE.png) the group in picture (use java). I think it's can be normal jbutton, and not jlabel either. what kind of control i can use to create that group?

Comment: Wath librery do you use SWT, Swing, ... ??

Comment: what libray can help me create that ? i just need to create that group. it doesn't matter what library is

Comment: @TrầnVănThành What do you mean by a "group" ?

Comment: @user3437460 i mean it has three buttons (it is not button actually but i don't know what it is)

Comment: @TrầnVănThành So your so called "grouping" is nothing but placing the buttons close together right?

Comment: Take a look in this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/GroupExamples.htm) and you can add button or images to it. is that good enough??

Comment: @user3437460 oh is it just 3 images place close together ? i will try it

Comment: @TrầnVănThành There are many ways to do it. The simplest would be using 3 buttons and place them together. An alternative would be using Graphics. But that requires a lot of knowledge in Java Swing.